Can't read the numbers in the calendar in QGIS because it is too dark
When I create a layer with a date field in QGIS 3.34.4 and activate the NOT NULL restriction in the layer options, the background color in the layer formular let the numbers disappear. I couldn't find any options in QGIS to change the theme. Any help? My QGIS style is "Fusion" and the theme is in "default", but changing that didn't help either.
Layer options:

Formular:


Changing the UI theme should have an effect. Did you restart after changing the setting? I tested with the "Blend of Gray" style. Unfortunately with this style many other items in the UI are almost invisible, but the calendar widget is more usable.

A hard way would be to create a new theme. On my computer they are in C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\resources\themes\. Copy one of the pre-installed styles and start editing the .qss files.
